# How to join in a meeting in zoom room app , from another app

Tags: android, zoom-sdk

In android I can join to zoom meeting , from another app like following

```
private void launchZoomUrl() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("zoomus://zoom.us/join?confno=7618757358&pwd=ghR5nb"));
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The above method , will open the zoom app , and directly join in the meeting  , where id is **7618757358** and password is **ghR5nb**

But I want to do the same thing , with zoom room app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=us.zoom.zrc). User will give input meeting id and password or meeting link , it will directly join a meeting in zoom room app .

Comment: You should look at the Docs if there is any intent URI provides by Zoom. I guess here is the [Doc](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/additional-tips/launch-zoom-client-from-your-app).

Comment: I have already checked that , that doc says nothing about zoom room app

Comment: have you managed the use case where user has not installed zoom into device?